# SQL server convert a row data to column headers

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, pivot

I am using SQL Server 2008

I have a result1

```
ProductCode    ApprovedQuantity productlineid
----------------------------------------
599-128-001     1              1
599-129-001     0              1
```

result set 2

```
productlineid  Damage
------------------------------
   1           MissingCriticalComponents
   1           BrokenConnector/Clip
```

I want to join the above two results set from two select statements like below

```
 ProductCode    ApprovedQuantity   MissingCriticalComponents BrokenConnector/Clip
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
599-128-001     7
599-129-001     5
```

Result set 2 values are dynalic(i.e Type of damage is not fixed. It varies. )
I want to add the result set 2 row values as column value with result set 1 with empty/null row values.

I am able to join two select statements into one and a resut set like below

```
 ProductCode    ApprovedQuantity     Damage
--------------------------------------------------------    
599-128-001     7       Broken Connector/Clip
599-129-001     5       Broken Connector/Clip
599-128-001     7       Missing Critical Components
599-129-001     5       Missing Critical Components
```

Please give your inputs

### ***Update:***

This is for retail product purchase orders.PFB is simplified version of my Requirement.I have a productLine table,Product table, purchare order table and damagetype table.

Productline table

```
 Productlineid       productlinename
-------------------------------------
     1                   xx
     2                   yy
```

Product table

```
   ProductCode    Productlineid     .....
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
599-128-001     1
599-129-001     1
599-128-002     2
599-129-002     2
```

Damage table

```
productlineid  Damage
------------------------------
  1           MissingCriticalComponents
  1           BrokenConnector/Clip
  2           water damaged
  2           brokenLens
```

Orderdetails table

```
  ProductCode    ApprovedQuantity     OrderID
--------------------------------------------------------    
599-128-001     7       101
599-129-001     5       101
599-128-001     7       102
599-129-001     5       102
```

UI : There is a order management screen with  export to excel option / Grid view

With Order id as input , I need to fetch order details along its damage types as new colums with empty row value. Through Excel or grid, they will update the damaged units with each order.

My goal is to get the result set as shown below

```
 ProductCode    ApprovedQuantity   MissingCriticalComponents BrokenConnector/Clip
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
599-128-001     7
599-129-001     5
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have updated by question.

Comment: Can you give us your REQUEST for result 1 and 2? It's not clear. In the table 2, there is a column damage, with values, and in the table 3, the values of damage are now columns?. Can you give us your table description you are using for your request? There is a missing table?

Comment: What is supposed to go under the new column headers?  Do you want the sum of the quantity under the new columns?  The desired result is a bit confusing.

Comment: I need to fetch order details along its damage types as new colums with empty row value. Please find my update

Answer (score 0):

You just want a SELECT QUERY that will give you the third table you show right?

Assuming, your two result are two select on single table...

```
SELECT T1.productCode, T1.ApprovedQuantity, T2.Damage
FROM TABLE1 T1
LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2 ON T2.productlineid  = T1.productlineid
```

Is that what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Please find more details in my update.